# How to use links to download PDF files in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

this is a bit silly but I am having problems to open one PDF tab in my Vue application with NUXT and Vuetify..

I am trying to use

```
<a href="../static/docs/filename.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

I also tried to use `<nuxt-link>` but didn't work.

The file is placed inside ~/static/docs folder.

The answer I receive is "This page could not be found"

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, It didn't work. Using an external link it's fine.

Comment: Care to explain? Whats external? So you didn't try `/static/docs/filename.pdf`?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, I tried but even after the build it wasn't working. My solution was use the FTP where the site is being hosted. I created one "docs" folder, uploaded the PDF there and used the HTTP link.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having the same trouble as you a few months back.

While looking at some older code it turns out I used a module called [vue-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf).

After declaring the module as a component like so:

```
components : {
  pdf : PDFViewer,
}
```

You can just use it in your markup by passing in your link:

```
<pdf :pdf="brochureDocument"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @user7388458.  

The vue-pdf link is not working but I found this one instead: 
https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf (same one). 

I also choose a different approach.. All the docs/PDF files will be in the server then I can easily use one http link instead of installing another module.

Thanks!